# google-cast for iOS SDK crashes on launch can't find class CADPCastErrorInfo

Tags: ios, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I installed the sdk with PODs, app compile fine. But on launch it then crashes saying it's missing the class CADPCastErrorInfo

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (CADPCastErrorInfo) for key (NS.objects) because no class named "CADPCastErrorInfo" was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target). If the class was renamed, use setClassName:forClass: to add a class translation mapping to NSKeyedUnarchiver'

Comment: I've encountered the same. problem. What's the version of your Cast SDK, `4.7.0`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems they now fixed this. Make sure you use their latest release.